# asyncExec freezing Window

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, rcp

I start a build script which takes about 2-3min and redirect the output into a StyledText (Text field)

The problem is that the program freezes (not responding) after 1-2 seconds of execution

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                                "cmd.exe", 
                                "/c", 
                                "cd \"" + binDir + "\" && " + entityDeployerParam);

final Process pRef = builder.start();
parent.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(pRef.getInputStream());
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            console.append(sc.nextLine()+"\n");
        }

    }
});
```

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should have the async inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Could you post how exactly, I've tried it but now it freezes even before the program can do anything. __Edit:__ Tried it in several ways, every asyncExec inside the while-loop freezes the program instantly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try `syncExec` instead.

Comment: sync it freezes like the first snippet i posted. Not as quick as the async but also after 1 sec.
I've also tried it with: exactly the same problem
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
       InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      
       String line;
       while(true){
      
       line = br.readLine();
       if(line == null) break;
       final String lRef = line;
      
       parent.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       console.append(lRef+"\n");
       }
       });
       }

Comment: What thread is starting this in the first place?

Comment: It is called inside an actionListener

Comment: Looks like the `Scanner.nextLine` calls are running in the UI thread and are blocking the thread. The whole thing needs to run in a separate thread and use `asyncExec` to update for each line.

Comment: I already tried this :/ - had not much time to solve the problem.. deadline.. realized it in an other way. When I have time I am going to try it and post my result. If it works I let you know